# Android MediaController in Fragment while audio is playing in Service

Tags: android, audio, android-fragments

I have an Activity that uses Fragments to display various screens. One of the screens is used to play an Audio File.  When the user selects the audio file to play, I start a Service and play the audio on that Service so that it will continue to play in the background even when the users returns to the home screen.

My question is this.  How do I use the MediaController in the fragment to reflect what is happening in the Service, so that I don't have to re-invent all of the controls of the MediaController?

I can create the MediaController in my fragment and display it, however the mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this); sets the controller to my fragment, correct?  How do I get it to set to my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your `Service` implement `MediaPlayerControl`, example...

```
public class MyMusicService extends Service
    implements MediaPlayerControl {

    ...

    // Override the various `MediaPLayerControl` methods
}
```

Now, in order for your `Fragment` to use the `MediaPlayerControl` it must bind to the `Service`. Add the following to the `Service`...

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyMusicService getService() {
        return MyMusicService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

Now you need to add the ability to bind to your `Service` in your `Fragment` code -*NOTE*, I've only done this with an `Activity` but the theory is the same for a `Fragment`. Add a `ServiceConnection` to your `Fragment` code...

```
MyMusicService mService = null;
boolean mBound;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

You can bind to your `Service` in the `onResume()` and unbind in `onPause()` of your `Fragment` and if you add the following to your `Fragment` you can set the `MediaController` to be the `Service`...

```
public void showMediaControllerHere() {
    if (mBound){
        controller.setMediaPlayer(mService);
        controller.setEnabled(true);
        controller.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Squonk !!!! I was close.  I had just started to implement iBinder and your controller.setMediaPlayer(mService) was just what was missing!!!  In the ServiceConnection, I had to change binder.getService() to binder.getServerInstance();

Comment: Glad I helped. I guess you can call the method anything you like as long as it returns a reference to the `Service`